# pandas how to get correct data type to use resample()

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and wondered why my code didn't work. I have a data file where it has some login_time time stamps (have an example at the end). I load the data from json to DataFrame, then try to aggregate it every 30 minutes. Got an error complaining about data type.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

input_file = 'data.json'
df = pd.read_json(input_file)
#df['count'] = 1
df.set_index('login_time');

print df.head()

agg_30m = pd.DataFrame()
agg_30m['login_time'] = df.login_time.resample(rule='30Min', how = 'last')
agg_30m['count'] = df.login_time.resample(rule='30Min', how = 'count')

print agg_30m.head()
```

samples of data in data.json file:

```
{"login_time":["2010-01-01 00:12:00","2010-01-01 00:21:00","2010-01-01 00:22:00","2010-01-01 00:23:00","2010-01-01 00:24:00"]}
```

Errors:

```
   agg_15m['login_time'] = df.login_time.resample(rule='15Min', how = 'last')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 4212, in resample
    base=base, key=on, level=level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 944, in resample
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 1057, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'
```

Comment: `resample` will only work with datetimeindex so is your index this type? if not you may need to do `df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

Comment: additionally `set_index` by default is not inplace, try `df.set_index('login_time', inplace=True)` you may still need to cast to datetimeindex like I suggested above

Comment: When I "print df.info()", I saw the data was "datetime64" type, then I set_index('login_time') to convert it to index. Why this wouldn't convert it datetimeindex? It looks like df.login_time was considered "Int64Index", which I didn't understand.

Comment: please see my comment about `set_index` not being in place. also look at what `df.index` shows